# Калькулятор ИМТ на Phyton. Синтаксис для новичка

Tags: python

первый раз пишу что-то на пайтоне, бекграунд в языках у меня небольшой. Вот код программы, которую я написал для расчета ИМТ:

```
weight = int('Weight: ')
height = int(float('Height: ') )

Underweight = range(0 , 18.5)
Normal = range(18.5 , 24.9)
Overweight = range(25 , 29.9)
Obesity = range(30 , 100)

imt = (float('weight') / float(int('height'**2) )

if(float(imt)) == (float(Underweight)):
    print('Underweight')
elif (float(imt) == float(Normal)):
    print('Normal')
elif (float(imt) == float(Overweight)):
    print('Overweight')
elif(float(imt) == float(Underweight)):
    print('Underweight')
```

Компилятор ругается на синтаксис 11 строчки, а именно на двоеточие после оператора

`if(float(imt)) == (float(Underweight)):`

Мне кажется, что я правильно все написал в этом блоке... По идеи если можно оперировать диапазонами в этом случае, то в целом программа должна работать. Чисто на взгляд новичка)

Comment: У вас проблема со скобками в предыдущей строке (открыто больше, чем закрыто). Вообще не нужно все оборачивать в скобки, лучше ставить их только там, где они нужны, тогда сложнее ошибиться.

Comment: Ну и вообще еще несколько проблем: в первых строках нужно запрашивать данные через input, а вы просто строки пытаетесь привести к int и float. И дальше в строке `imt = (float('weight') / float(int('height'**2) )` опять текстовые строки пытаетесь в числа превратить.

Comment: https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2686226/bmi-calculator-python-beginner-project